# Graph: get Friend Activity for a page, like the tab

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Anyone know of a way to get the feed of info for "Friend Activity" shown on a Facebook page?
[image: example friend activity]
I'm trying to include this in an iPhone app!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use FQL to query the stream table.  Put in a WHERE clause to filter the results to items posted by any of your friend IDs ( `IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()`) and also WHERE the post is made on the page.

For FQL stream info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

For playing around with the Query to get it right: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Actually, this will only show when your friends post on that page's Wall. This doesn't take into account several other items that show up in this Friend Activity, such as likes, shares, mentions, or if your friends are tagged by the Page. Any thoughts on how to accomplish that? The stream table doesn't seem to have all of that info available.